# Python Memory Allocation Error

Tags: python, memory, timeout, subprocess

I am having a problem with memory allocation in python which seems odd because I think my script should use constant memory. I run an external script using subprocess then record the result. Sometimes the script takes too long so I have a timeout exception set up. here is what I have:

```
class Timeout():
    """Timeout class using ALARM signal."""
    class Timeout(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec

    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.raise_timeout)
        signal.alarm(self.sec)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        signal.alarm(0)    # disable alarm

    def raise_timeout(self, *args):
        raise Timeout.Timeout()

def simulate(Length, Time, parameters, conditions):
    args = tuple(list(np.append(parameters, np.append([Length, Time], conditions))))
    cmd = './simulate.m %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % args
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    try:
        with Timeout(2):
            string = proc.stdout.read()
            result = (float(re.sub(r'\*\^', 'e', string)))
    except ValueError:
        print "ValueError", parameters
        result = np.linalg.norm(parameters) * 100.0
    except Timeout.Timeout:
        print "TimeoutException", parameters
        result = np.linalg.norm(parameters) * 100.0
    except:
        print "Other Exception"
        result = np.linalg.norm(parameters) * 100.0
    finally:
        proc.terminate()

    return result
```

I call it and print the result in a loop:

```
iters = 0

while iters < 100000:
    conditions = random_conditions()
    parameters = (np.random.rand(7) * 10) - 5
    length = np.random.randint(500 - 75) + 75
    time = np.random.randint((7200 - 3600) * 2) + 3600
    fraction = simulate(length, 7200, parameters, conditions)

    if fraction <= 1.0:
        print ','.join(map(lambda num: str(num), np.concatenate(([time], [length], parameters, conditions, [fraction]))))
        iters += 1
```

After about 500 tries I get a memory allocation error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Data_Generation.py", line 27, in <module>
    fraction = simulate(length, 7200, parameters, conditions)   File "/home/***/Documents/Lab_Program/approximator/data_generation/simulation_utils.py", line 27, in simulate
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1223, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork() OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Why would this be happening? I close the process and print the result with each iteration. Shouldn't this be constant memory? It seems to happen near a timeout error.

Edit* I tried killing the subprocesses as suggested in this answer. Instead of using proc.terminate(). It went further (though that could just be random) and hit the same error.

Edit** I solved this in an extremely hacky way. I know that any process that might be generated would have a name that matches a particular regex. I simply used `pgkill -9 -f regex` to kill all of the processes that weren't getting killed. I know those processes spawn no children so this is somewhat safe. If anyone has any insights about a cleaner solution I would love to hear.

Comment: You should do `proc.wait` after terminate to make sure you clean up zombie processes in the proc table. You could even do `proc.wait(timeout=10)` - if you hit that timeout, it means the proc didn't really terminate. Also, try converting your command to a list and doing `shell=False` ... you are killing the outer shell, not the program and that can be problematic.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the shell for this particular command.

Comment: Maybe not. Python is running a shell to run the command, that's all. Its useful if you are doing shell redirection or variable substitution but those can be handled by python. It appears as though you have many instances of this command in the background. That's the thing to puzzle out.